# AJAX question: server is not returning proper status code in the event of a error

Tags: ajax, error-handling, http-status-codes

While designing a error handling mechanism for AJAX script on my website, I found that the only status code that was returned, by the server, in the event of a error was 0 (or "undefined"). Even when I intentionally created a 404 error by requesting a non-existent file, the only error code that was returned by the server was 0. I believe that this problem is caused by my web-host's server (www.000webhost.com) when it redirects 404 errors to http://error404.000webhost.com/? however, I need to find a way to get a proper error code from the server's response in order to deliver feedback to the user on what went wrong... So my question is: how do I make the server return the proper status code, or if that is not the problem: what is wrong with my code?

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {

    alert(xmlhttp.status); //this alert box shows 200 normally, but during a error only shows 0

if (xmlhttp.status==200) { // 200 = OK, process result

//stuff for processing the result (when there is no error)

}
else { // error handling (creates a jgrowl notification showing the status code)
    $('#jGrowl-container').jGrowl('AJAX Error Code: ' + xmlhttp.status', {sticky: true, theme: 'error'});
}
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "process.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("&s="+ScoutID + "&pw="+pword + "&rt="+RequestType + RequestText);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live page you can point us to? Also, you're running this script locally from the filesystem are you? Because that's the only case I know of that would return a code of `0` instead of a `200`.

Comment: If your host has a redirect on errors, then you have to ask them about it. Unless you control the server, you can't stop them from taking a 4xx response and turning it into a 302 redirect.

Comment: yes I do have a live page http://slang.net78.net/query.html (its still under construction, so it looks kinda ugly) also the script points to a non-existant file to cause a error. And no it's not being hosted locally. Also, do you know of any way to prevent 000webhost from taking a 4xx response and turning it into a 302 redirect by using the .htaccess file (which I have access to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be different reasons why you are NOT getting proper http-status codes in response.

1. Check with your hosting provider whether they are handling or have customized the web server for this. You can check it in their control panel or ask their helpdesk.
2. Your server is redirecting in case of 404 which may not let the browser track it as 404 but instead a 302 or 303 (redirection). Few hosting companies do that.

Also I noticed that you are using jQuery already so why not use it for your ajax calls as well. It works well. You can check it out at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: I haven't gotten a reply from my hosting company yet, but that sounds like what is happening. Also, thank you for the tip about using jQuery for Ajax calls.